# setup.py doesn't find tensorflow==2.0 dependency (found tensorflow==2.0.0b0)

Tags: tensorflow, setuptools, setup.py, tensorflow2.0

I have a package that has a `setup.py` configuration with the `tensorflow==2.0` dependency. I install it with `python setup.py develop`.

It used to be the `tensorflow==2.0.0b0` version and it worked fine. I just tried to upgrade to the officially released version (`tensorflow==2.0`) and setuptools starts complaining that it can't satisfy this requirement.

After trying to dig into that, I got to a difference between the platform tags of TF beta0 and TF2.0 (beta0 is marked as `manylinux1` while versions after that are `manylinux2010`).

I'm not very familiar with python installations internals and doesn't quite understand the subtlety between the two versions..
Can I declare my package to be `manylinux2010`? (I understand that's the newer one). Will it look for dependencies that match that platform and find TF?  If that's not the way - can anyone give me a hint as for what I should be looking for?...

Many thanks,
Zach

**EDIT: Adding logs**

I'm running this from the GitLab CI docker image, which is a Linux machine. When I run locally (MacOS) it works. Also - Python version is 3.6.5

```
root@430fc49e1d2d:/builds/analytics/frgpy# python setup.py develop
running develop
running egg_info
writing frgpy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to frgpy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to frgpy.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to frgpy.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'frgpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/frgpy.egg-link (link to .)
frgpy 1.0.7.dev11+gc088f0b.d20191105 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /builds/analytics/frgpy
Processing dependencies for frgpy==1.0.7.dev11+gc088f0b.d20191105
Searching for tensorflow==2.0.0
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/
No local packages or working download links found for tensorflow==2.0.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow==2.0.0')
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: sorry.. it's some sort of Linux (it's GitLab CI runner. `uname` gives `4.19.76-linuxkit #1 SMP Thu Oct 17 19:31:58 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

Comment: Could you post the exact stacktrace.

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: @sinoroc - python 3.6.5

Comment: @gobrewers14 - added the terminal logs to the question.

Comment: What's the docker image?

Comment: Are you using `docker:latest` by any chance?

Comment: it's a private docker image we've created to run our CI tests. It's based on Debian 8 (jessie). Docker itself (on my local machine) was updated to the latest version (Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf5).

Comment: (our docker image is actually based on 'python:3.6.5' which is a Debian8 distro)

Comment: just adding - checked now with 'python:3.8.0-buster' docker image and I still can't get it to install any TF2.0 version (not the beta). Tried '==2.0', '==2.0.0', and '~=2.0'.
I'm not sure what's the difference between manylinux1 and manylinux2010 but this seems to be the difference.

Comment: Probably the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60729752/2650249) - you have to update `setuptools` to at least 42.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

The version is named [2.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history) so try

```
tensorflow==2.0.0
```

Comment: tried that. didn't help... 
also tried many variations of "~=2.0", ">=2.0.0", etc...