# Cant Install Tensorflow 2.2.0rc0 in Ubuntu with Github Actions inside setup.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, github-actions

When i try to install `tensorflow>=2.2.0rc0` from `setup.py` running `python setup.py install` from a Github Actions Workflow, the output sendme this:

```
Searching for tensorflow>=2.2.0rc0
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/
No local packages or working download links found for tensorflow>=2.2.0rc0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow>=2.2.0rc0')
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This is my Github Action Workflow:

```
name: Test Deblurrer

on: 
  push:
    branches:
    - master
    - development 
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master
    - development

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.7]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Setup Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python setup.py install
        pip install pytest

    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/runner/work/deep-deblurring/deep-deblurring/backend:$(pwd)
        pytest
```

next is my setup.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

"""Setup and install the package and all the dependencies."""

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as pro:
    INSTALL_REQUIRES = pro.read().split('\n')

setup(
    author='Whitman Bohorquez, Mo Rebaie',
    author_email='whitman-2@hotmail.com',
    name='deblurrer',
    license='MIT',
    description='Image Deblurring using Deep Learning Architecture',
    version='1.0.0',
    url='',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIRES,
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: Alpha',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    ],
)
```

and by last, my requirements.txt:

```
grpcio == 1.27.2
kaggle
numpy
tensorflow >= 2.2.0rc0
pandas
```

I dont understand why this happen on Github Actions, but when installing locally on Windows 10 it works as expected.

Thanks in advance!

PD: When i exec `pip install tensorflow==2.2.0rc0` directly on the Github Action Workflow, and not inside `python setup.py install` it works too. So this dont work on `setup.py` only, and on Ubuntu only

Comment: Shouldn't `install_requires` be a `list`? In your case it's just a `str`. You could use this: `["".join(requirement.split()) for requirement in pro.read().split("\n")]` to split it correctly instead of `pro.read()`.

Secondly, you don't need `extras_require` which are exactly the same as `INSTALL_REQUIRES` and aren't either `list` or `map`  and if you are testing something you should use `tox`, `pytest` or a-like.

Lastly, your `pwd` might be wrong here, if you want to be in the same place as `setup.py` during read this comes in handy: `HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent`

Comment: Thanks for pinpoint that, i will do that fixes and come back!

Comment: `python setup.py install` uses `setuptools` under the hood. What `setuptools` version do you use? You can check that with e.g. `python3 -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.__version__)"`. It looks like `setuptools` on your target machine is rather old and doesn't support the `manylinux_2010` tag. Check that via `python3 -c "from setuptools import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_supported()[0])"` - what is printed, `manylinux1_x86_64`?

Comment: Hello @hoeflingHola it prints a blank line when execute the little script

Comment: @SzymonMaszke i already clean the setup.py module, but it keeps mentioning the error, i refactor your code a bit to be clearer, install_requires dont need the lines to have no spaces. and by pwd, i feel it dont have nothing to do with the problem, i already pass the test suit with pytest and everything fine when tensorflow its installed directly by the workflow. Everything mess up when i let the setup.py install tensorflow

Comment: @hoefling and update, i tried to execute it line by line using python interpreter, but it trows error: ```from setuptools import pep425tags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'pep425tags' from 'setuptools' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\deblurrer\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py)``` and about setuptools version it is 46.0.0

Comment: @ElPapi42 You are saying you have an error on Linux, but execute the command on Windows. You should add both commands to Github Actions yaml config and trigger the pipeline to see the output on target system.

Comment: Ohh that is right! sorry for that! let me check

Comment: This is the output ```41.2.0``` and ```('cp37', 'cp37m', 'manylinux1_x86_64')``` can be an outdated stuptools? PD: im testing it, seemslike it works, can you submit that as posible solution?

Comment: Definitely - [the support for `manylinux2010` tag was added in 42.0.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v42-0-0). Upgrading `setuptools` will resolve the issue.

Comment: @hoefling that solved the issue, can you post the solution here? for accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with an outdated `setuptools` version. Since 2.0, `tensorflow` only ships wheels with the `manylinux2010` tag on Linux. `setuptools` has added support for `manylinux2010` [in 42.0.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v42-0-0), so upgrading `setuptools` will resolve the issue:

```
$ pip install setuptools>=42.0.0
```

Comment: for add up, Actually Github Actions Containers ships with setuptools==41.2.0, this can surely change in the future